# Fabric.js: How to remove padding and format selection box? (padding still exists after zoom)

Tags: fabricjs

I am trying to format selection border style to look like in inkscape(image left side).
I have tried to set the object padding to zero with this:

```
fabric.Object.prototype.set({
    padding: 0,
});
```

If I zoom in this is more apparent and padding grows.

Example: [Left side inkscape selection box style, right side actual fabric.js selection box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7sN7.jpg)

How can i remove the padding?

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ecco512/p89sd1a8/).

Comment: Try `padding : 0`, while you are adding objects to canvas.

Comment: I tried but the padding is 0 already. I think this problem related to zoom function in fabricjs. At default zoom the padding between the object and the border is barely noticable.

Comment: can you make a fiddle/snippet ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ecco512/p89sd1a8/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because of stroke width, set `strokeWidth:0` to object.

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = window.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
 
var rect = new fabric.Rect({left: 10, top: 10,strokeWidth:0, width: 60, height: 60, fill: 'blue'});

rect.editable = true;
rect.customType = 'shape';
rect.describtion = 'fabric.js rect object';
rect.cornerColor = 'red';
rect.borderColor = 'red';
rect.cornerSize = 8;
rect.padding = 0;

canvas.add(rect);
canvas.setActiveObject(rect);
canvas.setZoom(20);
```

```css
canvas{
 border:2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```